# jQuery .find() result undefined

Tags: jquery, find, undefined

Hi I'm having a problem displaying the result I get back from my php file.

jquery part:

```
$("#dates").load('input_date.php');
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        onClose: function() { 

            var $form = $( "#input" ),
            treat = $('#treatment option:selected').val(),
            book = $( '#datepicker' ).val(),
            url = "input_date.php" ;

            $.post( url , { treatment: treat, bookdate: book  },
                function(data) {
                    var content = $( data ).find( '#timeslots' );
                    alert(treat);
                    console.log(content);
                    $( "#dates" ).empty().append( content );}


            /*$.post( "input_date.php" , { treatment: treat, bookdate: book  },
                function(data) {
                    var $data = $(data);
                    var content = $data.is('#timeslots') ?   $data : $data.find('#timeslots');
                    alert(content);
                    $( "#dates" ).empty().append( content );}*/
        );



    }});
```

php part (in input_date.php)

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$treatment = $_POST['treatment'];
$bookdate = $_POST['bookdate'];
if(isset($treatment) && isset($bookdate)){

$exp = explode("-", $bookdate);

//determine what day of the week it is
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$exp[1],$exp[0],$exp[2]);
$dw = date( "w", $timestamp); // sun0,mon1,tue2,wed3,thur4,fri5,sat6
echo $dw."weekday"; //week day 
echo"<br/>";

//find bookings with same date
$q = mysql_query("SELECT BOOK_SLOT_ID FROM BOOKINGS WHERE BOOK_DATE='$bookdate'");
//make array of booking slots
$array1 = array();
while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
$array1[] = $s['BOOK_SLOT_ID'];
}
$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT SL_ID FROM SLOTS");
//make array of all slots
$array2 = array();
while ($s2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
$array2[] =  $s2['SL_ID'];
}

//remove bookings from all slots
$arr_res = array_diff($array2, $array1);

//make selectable options of results
echo '<SELECT id="timeslots">';
foreach($arr_res as $op){
$r = mysql_query("SELECT SL_TIME FROM SLOTS WHERE SL_ID='$op'");
$q3 = mysql_fetch_array($r);
echo "<OPTION value=".$op.">".$q3['SL_TIME']."</OPTION>";
}
echo '</SELECT>';
}else{
$else = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SLOTS");
echo '<SELECT>';
while($array_else = mysql_fetch_array($else)){
echo "<OPTION value=".$array_else['SL_ID'].">".$array_else['SL_TIME']."</OPTION>";
}
echo "</SELECT>";
print $bookdate;
}

?>
```

Big update: I found an error in the $.post part which was causing the variables not to be passed on to the php correctly. Now If I check my console, initially it gives php undefined errors, however the return I get from post shows what it should show, it doesn't display in my #dates div. Any ideas on how to get the information to display? Thanks in advance

Comment: Also: JavaScript (and jQuery) works client-side. The client does not *see* PHP, it sees HTML. What HTML does your (server-side) PHP script return?

Comment: Have you checked the response you get from `input_date.php` in your browser's network or console tab? Is it what you are expecting? If the php file runs without errors (and doesn't output anything else) then the code should work

Comment: I currently also submit the form on this page to input_date.php and on that page it shows exactly what I want to see. 

I tried earlier posting values to a script to just upload records and that worked, so I think posting the same variables to this script should work too, and it should show me my select option list customised for available times..

Comment: But are you checking the response you're getting from `input_date.php`? Open the Developer Tools/Firebug depending if you're using Chrome or Firefox and check the Network tab after the request is made and see what you're getting back. From what I can tell you're expecting a `<select>` element with options in it, nothing more.

Comment: It does show me a that, it basicly gives me the same as I start with, except instead of get it's post response..  which is the full default array, along with two notices that variables are undefined.. Does this mean the $.post is not (correctly/in the right format) sending the variables?

Comment: I've just noticed your alert `alert(console.log(content))`. That's incorrect! `console.log()` always returns `undefined` as it's function is output data into the browser console. You either do `alert(content)` to output data in the alert box, or `console.log(content)` to output data in the browser console.

Comment: And if you're getting notices in your response then there are issues in you php code. If the response contains notices then the structure is most likely not valid html and jquery won't parse it correctly. Update your question and include the response you're getting from the server

Comment: I've updated my question. The notices are from php error reporting. I'm not sure why it sends me the same it sends before though because it should have received variables. MAybe the php file isn't updating? But then why don't I receive the default for when the input isn't set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.find()` only searches descendants of the given element, not the element itself. Since `#timeslots` is the toplevel element of the script output, it's not being found. You can write:

```
var $data = $(data);
var contents = $data.is('#timeslots') ? $data : $data.find('#timeslots');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's still not working correctly though. The part that should be dynamicly loaded also doesn't change and  my alert isn't working now. I believe that therefor the onclose function doesn't work anymore

Comment: BUT now I fixed the php part, this solution worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!